# jQuery appended html code CSS not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

My code html code:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mydiv">
       <div class="myclass">
          <p>hello world</p>
       </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

works perfectly fine and my css styling gets applied correctly.

But when I try to add the html via jquery (or java script innerHtml), the CSS styling doesn't get applied:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#mydiv').append('<div class="myclass">');
  $('#mydiv').append('<p>hello world</p>');
  $('#mydiv').append('</div>');
});
```

```css
.myclass p {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mydiv">
</div>
```

Comment: Your code works as supplied (see link in previous comment).  The code you supply needs to reproduce the problem.

Comment: looks like it only doesnt work if you have a sub-element. E.g. if myclass element is a div and has a p, the css code: .myclass p {color: red;} doesnt work.

Comment: None of the code currently supplied would be selected with `.myclass p`  as the `p` element has the class. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78216627/edit) your question with code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Now your javascript is not creating the same document elements as in your raw html. :(

Comment: But I think you will find in the end that your CSS works the same whether you are adding to the DOM with javascript or using static html  .... as long as the results is equivalent DOM with respect to the elements you want to be styled.

Comment: Use your browser's developer console to check what your code actually produces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you are appending your elements is incorrect.

`$('#mydiv').append('<div class="myclass">')` will append a `div` complete with closing tag.

`$('#mydiv').append('<p>hello world</p>');` will append that paragraph **after** the `myclass` div, not as a child of it.

You can see this by inspecting the rendered html using the browsers developer tools. Basically, `append()` appends content, not a string.

In this case just append all the HTML you need.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#mydiv').append('<div class="myclass"><p>hello world</p></div>');
});
```

```css
.myclass p {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mydiv">
</div>
```